# Flutter build error: Dart_LookupLibrary: library 'dart:cli' not found

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Any project (even completely new) I am trying to build in VS Code results in this:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi 5A in debug mode...
main.dart:1
Dart_LookupLibrary: library 'dart:cli' not found.
2
the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.
Exited (1)
```

If launched in Windows profile mode exception is more generous:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in profile mode...
main.dart:1
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(247,5): error MSB8066: Custom build for 'F:\FlutterProjects\flutter_application_1\build\windows\CMakeFiles\aae8d91d16e80640af0f833b3e3b445a\flutter_windows.dll.rule;F:\FlutterProjects\flutter_application_1\build\windows\CMakeFiles\0007e47bf58973ffb97fc5c3530dbc88\flutter_assemble.rule;F:\FlutterProjects\flutter_application_1\windows\flutter\CMakeLists.txt' exited with code 1. [F:\FlutterProjects\flutter_application_1\build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]
Exception: Build process failed.
```

I have tried: flutter clean, flutter doctor (no issues), reinstalled dart and flutter extensions.

I am going to reinstall vs code, but any ideas to try before?